# Java: Sort an array according to matching string / pattern

Tags: java, string, sorting, collections, comparator

I need to sort an array in which the matching items comes up and others will goes down.

For Ex. I have an Array : **[ z , asxdf , abasdf , abcasdf , b , bc , bcd , c ]**
What I need is when I pass a KeyWord suppose **"b"** , then it should sort the given array in which all the string starting with **b..** will come first and the rest after that. Which will generate final output : **[ b , bc , bcd , z , c , .. (rest).]**

If it is possible using comparator in Java ?

```
String keyWord = "b";
String[] s = {"z", "asxdf", "abasdf", "abcasdf", "b", "bc", "bcd", "c"};
Arrays.sort(s, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

            //Code to sort array according to need

    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

**`Result -> [ b , bc , bcd , z , c , ...]`**

(I may use List instead of Array, or any other if it help me solve this)

Comment: So you want us to do the compare algorithm for you?

Comment: Yes, If it does not harm you. But If you read my question again, you will see what I asked for "If it is possible using comparator in Java ?".

Comment: Does the algorithm have to be stable, I.e. does the order of elements within each of the 2 groups have to be the same as in the original array?

Comment: No, but priority will be for those who best matches the keyword.

Comment: what do you mean with "best matches"? either they match or they don't.

Comment: best match of 'b' will be 'b', 'bc' and 'bcd'. Of 'bc' will be 'bc' and 'bcd'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32368/discussion-between-shreyas-dave-and-user829755)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answering the question whether is possible to do it with a Comparator, the answer is yes: you just need to create a new Comparator class instead of creating an anonymous Comparator, like this:

```
    class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        private final String keyWord;

        MyComparator(String keyWord) {
            this.keyWord = keyWord;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

            if(o1.startsWith(keyWord)) {
                return o2.startsWith(keyWord)? o1.compareTo(o2): -1;
            } else {
                return o2.startsWith(keyWord)? 1: o1.compareTo(o2); 
            }
        }
    }
```

and then use that comparator in your code:

```
    String keyWord = "b";
    String[] s = {"z", "asxdf", "abasdf", "abcasdf", "b", "bc", "bcd", "c"};
    Arrays.sort(s, new MyComparator(keyWord));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

Comment: I had a similar approach. You beat me to it! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Because the strings length after the keyword matches appear to matter, here's my version:

```
Arrays.sort(s, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

        boolean o1Has = o1.startsWith( keyWord );
        boolean o2Has = o2.startsWith( keyWord );

        if( o1Has && !o2Has  ) return -1;
        else if( o2Has && !o1Has ) return 1;
        else if( o1Has && o2Has ) return 0;
        else
            return o1.length() - o2.length();
    }
});
```

Yields:

[b, bc, bcd, z, c, asxdf, abasdf, abcasdf]

Comment: @n0741337 thanks a lot! It worked :)

Answer (score 1):

```
final String keyWord = "b";
String[] s = {"z", "asxdf", "abasdf", "abcasdf", "b", "bc", "bcd", "c"};
Arrays.sort(s, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

            boolean o1_has_keyWord = o1.indexOf(keyWord.charAt(0)) == 0 && o1.contains(keyWord);
            boolean o2_has_keyWord = o2.indexOf(keyWord.charAt(0)) == 0 && o2.contains(keyWord);

        if (o1_has_keyWord && o2_has_keyWord)
        {
            if (o1.length() == o2.length())
            {
                if (o1.indexOf(keyWord.charAt(0)) > o2.indexOf(keyWord.charAt(0))){
                    return -1;
                }
                else if (o1.indexOf(keyWord.charAt(0)) == o2.indexOf(keyWord.charAt(0))){
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            else if (o1.length() > o2.length())
            {
                    return 1;
            }
            else 
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else if (o1_has_keyWord && !o2_has_keyWord)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (!o1_has_keyWord && o2_has_keyWord)
        {
            return 1;
        }


        return 0;

            //Code to sort array according to need

    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

Output:

```
[b, bc, bcd, z, asxdf, abasdf, abcasdf, c]
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, but problem is it works same for keywords = 'b', 'bc' and 'bcd'..

Comment: I thought you just want to use a single character for the keywords. I will update for a string used as keyword

Answer (score 1):

I will also add that you can read about `Comparator` and `Comparable` in this Oracle tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, will sure read it.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
List result = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
    if(s[i].startsWith(keyWord)) {
        result.add(s[i], 0);  // Adding to the beginning
    } else {
        result.add(s[i]);  // Adding to the end
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but I need to comparator and sort() method.

Answer (score 0):

just because it's shorter:

```
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    boolean firstMatches = o1.startsWith(keyWord);
    boolean secondMatches = o2.startsWith(keyWord);
    if (firstMatches != secondMatches) {
        return firstMatches ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return 0;  // or refine the sort sort here
}
```

Comment: Does this take care of this output?
[b, bc, bcd, z, c, asxdf, abcasdf, abasdf]

Sorry this does not work.

Comment: sorry but this does not work.

Comment: sorry, fixed the typo (o1 was used twice and o2 not at all)

Answer (score 0):

**Please check following**

```
package com.pantech.sam.demos;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortArray {

/**
 * @param args
 */
private final static char keyWord = 'b';

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] s = {"z", "asxdf", "abasdf", "abcasdf", "b", "bc", "bcd", "c"};

    System.out.println("FIRST WAY " + sortArray(s));

    Arrays.sort(s, new CustomeComparator(keyWord));
    System.out.println("SECOND WAY" + Arrays.toString(s));

}

static List<String> sortArray(String[] sArray){
    Arrays.sort(sArray) ;
    List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList(sArray);
    List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>(l1.size());
    int index = 0;
    for (String str : l1) {
        if (str.charAt(0) == keyWord) {
            l2.add(index++,str); // add at start
        }else{
            l2.add(l2.size(), str); // add at end
        }

    }
    return l2;
}

}


class CustomeComparator implements Comparator<String> {
private final char keyWord;

CustomeComparator(char keyword2) {
    this.keyWord = keyword2;
}


@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(o1.charAt(0) == (keyWord)) {
            return o2.charAt(0) == (keyWord)? o1.compareTo(o2): -1;
        } else {
            return o2.charAt(0) == (keyWord)? 1: o1.compareTo(o2); 
        }   }
}
```